# Alcatraz in Xcode 7.1

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode7.1, alcatraz

**Note that from Xcode 8 Alcatraz no longer works** 
[Editor Extension Tutorial](https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/how-to-create-an-xcode-source-editor-extension--cms-26772)

---

I am unable to install Alcatraz for Xcode 7.1

According to their twitter feed Alcatraz should work with Xcode 7.1. I have tried uninstalling and reinstalling.

I used the recommended install of

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.githubusercontent.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/deploy/Scripts/install.sh | sh
```

Could it be related to the fact I also have Xcode 6.4 installed?

[image]

Answer (score 53, accepted):

@Mopr answer will possibly resolve, but did not work for me. I got a more complete answer from Enisto Pino [Alcatraz issue 352](https://github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/issues/352#issuecomment-151273449) Which I am reposting here

1) Close Xcode

2) Remove previous defaults for Xcode 7.0

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTPlugInManagerNonApplePlugIns-Xcode-7.0
```

3) Uninstall Alcatraz

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins/Alcatraz.xcplugin
```

4) Remove all packages installed via Alcatraz

```
rm -rf ~/Library/Application\ Support/Alcatraz/
```

5) Update the DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID to the 7.1 in the plists of plugins:

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add defaults read /Applications/Xcode\ 7.1.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID
```

6) Reset Xcode select

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

7) Open Xcode

8) Install Alcatraz

```
curl -fsSL https://raw.github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/master/Scripts/install.sh | sh
```

9) Restart Xcode

10) Select "Load Bundles" in dialog box at Xcode start.

Comment: did not work for me. I even saw "Load Bundles", but Xcode still does not have "Package Manager" in Window

Comment: @Adem You should be using XCode 8+ now so this is no longer relevant

Answer (score 7):

I did the same as Ryan suggested and it didn't work. Then I realized his has:

> defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTPlugInManagerNonApplePlugIns-Xcode-7.0

Since I am on 7.1 I changed it to

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTPlugInManagerNonApplePlugIns-Xcode-7.1
```

P.S. I would make this a comment but I'm too much of a noob to make comments 3;(

Answer (score 6):

I had the same issue with 7.1 and just reinstalling Alcatraz didn't help. I also have XCode 6.4, which may be related.
I found the solution here - https://github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/issues/352

As mentioned by **welsonla**, you have to exit XCode and enter in terminal

```
find ~/Library/Application\ Support/Developer/Shared/Xcode/Plug-ins -name Info.plist -maxdepth 3 | xargs -I{} defaults write {} DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUIDs -array-add `defaults read /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Info DVTPlugInCompatibilityUUID`
```

then

```
sudo xcode-select --reset
```

I also uninstalled Alcatraz before that and reinstalled it after, just in case.

Comment: My other plugins now work but still no Alcatraz 7265231C-39B4-402C-89E1-16167C4CC990 was added to the info.plist but under window package manager nothing.

Answer (score 5):

I moved Alcatraz.xcplugin outside from the plug-in folder. Opened Xcode, then quit. Later I moved back into the plug-in folder and reopened Xcode. It asked me whether to load bundles, just hit load and it loaded. [github.com/supermarin/Alcatraz/issues/359]

Comment: Easiest and simplest answer. Might not work for everybody but it did the job for me. Thanks!