# Xcode package manager appears first but does not appear after

Tags: ios, xcode

The first time I run xcode7 after installed `alcatraz`,the package manager appeared, but when I restarted Xcode,the package manager disappeared (my plugins work well though the package manager is missing

I had tried to change `.plist` files, but it didn't work.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342969/alcatraz-in-xcode-7-1[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342969/alcatraz-in-xcode-7-1] This may help.

Comment: Previous link is bad. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33342969/alcatraz-in-xcode-7-1

Comment: I have dealt with this with your help,thanks a lot

Answer (score 0, accepted):

With the information from this [website](http://pablin.org/2015/05/27/re-enable-alcatraz-on-xcode-6-dot-3-2-or-newer/), I used the following shell instruction to reset the alert:

```
defaults delete com.apple.dt.Xcode DVTPlugInManagerNonApplePlugIns-Xcode-7.1
```

Maybe this helps here too.