# Xcode 8.1 Crashing on completion block

Tags: ios, xcode, xcode8

Whenever I use a closure and press enter for the suggestion my Xcode gets crashed. I am using Macbook Pro 15 Retina with graphics card 2015 Model. I am using latest OS Sierra 10.12.1. Never faced this kind of issue in Xcode 8. Any One having similar issue like me?

Comment: did you install alcatraz ?

Comment: Yes i did have installed alcatraz before.

Comment: see [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/33355962/2161945) answer

Comment: But Alcatraz doesn't seem to create crash as I have used Xcode 8 and there were no issues in that. Still I will try cleaning it and use.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- it seems to be fixed in Xcode 8.2.
- try upgrading your Xcode, it totally works fine for me in Xcode 8.2

Comment: Yes i am not facing such issues in newer Xcode. Btw thanks.